# Property 'withComponents' does not exist on type 'typeof AgGridModule'

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am using AG Grid in my Angular application and since upgrading from v27 to v28 I get the following error in my app.

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:18:18 - error TS2339: Property 'withComponents' does not exist on type 'typeof AgGridModule'.
```

I thought this was required when providing your own custom components to AG grid?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since v28 the AgGridModule no longer needs the `.withComponents()` method as all user applications will now be using Ivy. The method used to handle registering custom components as `EntryComponents` but that is no longer required with Ivy and was deprecated by Angular.

So to fix this error make the follow change and your custom components will still work.

```
- AgGridModule.withComponents([CustomComp]);
+ AgGridModule
```

See the AG Grid Docs on [Angular Compatibility](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/angular-compatibility/) for more details.